# How can I short this code with class and object

Tags: python, function, class, object, command-line

I am making an investment game in which the Gold and Bitcoin prices go down and up day by day but here I am getting a problem how can I make this code easy so I can add any other crypto and share with just 2-3 lines of code but now I have to code whole if-else statement to do this

Can I use Classes and objects but how

This is the code How can I Improve

```
goldPrice = 63 # $ dollars per gram
bitcoinPrice = 34000 # $ dollars per bitcoin
day = 1 # life start with this day

myGold = 0 # in Grams
myBitcoin = 0.0 # in bitcoin

def newspaper():
    print("GOLD: " + str(goldPrice) + '$ per gram')
    print("BITCOIN: " + str(bitcoinPrice) + "$")
    print("An investment in knowledge pays the best interest.")

def invest():

    global balance, myGold, myBitcoin

    print("====Which Thing you want to Buy====")

    print("1. Gold")
    print("2. Bitcoin")
    print("3. Nothing, Go Back")

    investInputKey = int(input())

    if investInputKey == 1:

        print("Gold: " + str(goldPrice) + ' per gram' +'\n')
        print("1. Buy")
        print("2. Sell")
        print("3. Exit")

        goldInput = int(input())

        if goldInput == 1:
            print("Enter Amount in Grams: ")
            howMuch = int(input())
            totalGoldBuy = howMuch * goldPrice
            print(totalGoldBuy)
            if totalGoldBuy > balance:
                print("Insufficient Balance!")
            else:
                print("Thank you! Have a Nice Day")
                balance -= totalGoldBuy
                myGold += howMuch

        elif goldInput == 2:
            print("Enter Amount in Grams: ")
            howMuch = int(input())
            if howMuch > myGold:
                print("Insufficient Gold!")
            else:
                print("Thank you! Have a Nice Day")
                myGold -= howMuch
                newGold = howMuch * goldPrice
                balance += newGold
        elif goldInput == 3:
            print("Thank you! Have a Nice Day")
        else:
            print("Wrong Input!")

    elif investInputKey == 2:
        print("Bitcoin: " + str(bitcoinPrice) +'\n')
        print("1. Buy")
        print("2. Sell")
        print("3. Exit")

        bitcoinInput = int(input())

        if bitcoinInput == 1:
            print("Enter Bitcoin Amount in Dollars")
            howMuch = int(input())
            if howMuch > balance:
                print("Insufficient Balance!")
            elif howMuch > 500:
                myBitcoin = howMuch / bitcoinPrice
                balance -= howMuch
            else:
                print("You can only buy above 500$")

                
        elif bitcoinInput == 2:
            print("Enter Bitcoin Amount in Dollars")
            howMuch = int(input())
            if howMuch > (myBitcoin * bitcoinPrice):
                print("Insufficient Bitcoin");
            elif howMuch < 500:
                print("You can only sale above 500 Dollars")
            else:
                myBitcoin -= howMuch / bitcoinPrice
                balance += howMuch
        elif goldInput == 3:
            print("Thank you! Have a Nice Day")
        else:
            print("Wrong Input!")

    elif investInputKey == 3:
        print("Thank you! Have a Nice Day");
    else:
        print("Wrong Input!")





while True:
    print("========HOME========" + '\n')
    print("====Day-" + str(day) + "====")
    print("====Balance-" + str(balance) + "$ ====")
    print('\n')

    print("1. Newspaper")
    print("2. Invest")
    print("3. My Portfolio")
    print("4. Next Day")
    print("5. Exit")

    inputKey = int(input())

    if inputKey == 1:
        newspaper()
    elif inputKey == 2:
        invest()
    elif inputKey == 3:
        print("========Portfolio========" + '\n')
        print("Gold: " + str(myGold) + " gram")
        print("Bitcoin: " + str(myBitcoin))
    elif inputKey == 4:
        day += 1
        print("This is day " + str(day))
        # Change price of gold and bitcoin
    elif inputKey == 5:
        # Add sure you want to exit
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong Input! Try Again")
```

Help me,
Thank You

Comment: Have a look at the [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) package to help with building a REPL.

Comment: Try codereview stack exchange, they'll be able to answer your question.